# Problems matching string between quotes but not if lines starts with %

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to re(encode) a decoded `LC_TIME` (locale) file. I want to match all strings that are between quotes, but not if they are part of a comment, comment lines start with a `%`.

`r'"([^"]*)"'` works fine to match all strings between quotes, but it doesn't check if it's part of a comment.

To clarify:

```
abday   "Sun";"Mon";/
    "Tue";"Wed";/
    "Thu";"Fri";/
    "Sat"
```

should result in seven matches

```
d_fmt   "%m/%d/%Y"
```

should result in one match

```
% Appropriate time representation (%X)
%   "%r"
```

should **not** result in a match

**Note:**
`re.findall('^(?!%).*?"([^"]*)"', text, flags=re.M)` almost does the trick, but it only matches `['Sun', 'Tue', 'Thu', 'Sat']` in the `abday` example.

See [this link](https://github.com/Oefenweb/glibc-locale-tools/pull/7/files#diff-850fddce820dbba0c93c3a5381846131R75) for tests on multiple cases.

Comment: How are you *applying* the regex? If you're processing each line in turn, just check `not line.startswith('%')`.

Comment: Full file content. Not line by lines, because quoted strings can span multiple lines.

Comment: That's going to be very tricky with a regular expression, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get it to work with a regex. Tried a different approach. Marking so called "unsafe spans" (comment lines that contain double quotes (that should not be (en|de)coded)). See [this changeset](https://github.com/Oefenweb/glibc-locale-tools/pull/7/files#diff-25e5e855d649b4069c25c703d6111cd0R13) for the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead assertion:

```
>>> text = '''
a "quoted" element
% "Comment"
"something else"
'''
>>> re.findall('^(?!%).*?"([^"]*)"', text, flags=re.M)
['quoted', 'something else']
>>> re.findall('^(?!%)[^"]*"([^"]*)"', text, flags=re.M)
['quoted', 'something else']
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two of them?

Comment: No difference :) Just a little variation: .*? and [^"]* after lookahead.

Comment: Did you read the note? I edited my question. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I did. See my another answer (as I didn't finally manage to insert formatted code into comment).

Comment: Thanks anyway for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Your hang up will be matching a line starting in a `"` cause that prevents you from being able to just do: `"^\s*[^%] ... "`

You can solve that with this regex:

```
(?:^\s*[^%].*?\"|^\s*\")([^\"]*)\"
```

However that will only capture the first string in quotes. You can just add another capture on to this to grab the second string in quotes:

```
(?:^\s*[^%].*?\"|^\s*\")([^\"]*)\"(?:[^\"]*\"([^\"]*)\")?
```

But if you need to support capturing an indeterminate number of strings in quotes you'll need to use [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) or something similar with a regex like this:

```
(?:^\s*[^%].*?\"|^\s*\")([^\"]*)\"(?:[^\"]*\"([^\"]*)\")*
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it could be simplier and easy-to-read to apply something like this:

```
import re

with open('sample.txt') as file:
    text = ''.join((line for line in file if line[0] != '%'))
    print re.findall('"(.*?)"', text, flags = re.M | re.S)
```

UPDATE #1:

```
with open('sample.txt') as file:
    text = ''.join(line.lstrip('+').replace('/\n', '') for line in file)

for line in text.splitlines():
    if line and line[0] != '%':
        for item in re.findall('"(.*?)"', line):
            print  item
```

Comment: Probably but it is also possible that the first character of a line is a % but that it's between quotes so it should not be ignored.. See: https://github.com/Oefenweb/glibc-locale-tools/pull/7/files#diff-850fddce820dbba0c93c3a5381846131R168

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple regex can capture both the comments and the quoted strings, and then you just filter out the comments:

```
[quoted for comment, quoted in re.findall(r'(^%.*)|"([^"]*)"',t, re.M) if not comment]
```

If it is OK to ignore empty quoted strings, a slightly simpler version will do:

```
[quoted for quoted in re.findall(r'^%.*|"([^"]*)"',t, re.M) if not quoted]
```